# next/navigation not available in my Nextjs 13 app

Tags: next.js

I am working on a NextJs app and below is my configuration:
Version: NextJs 13.5.2
Route: App route

I am trying to access the current url path, and i tried to import useRouter from next/navigation or even usePathName, but it is not present in my project.
I tried to use next/router but my project throws an error that it fails to mount.

Please how can i can I resolve this?

I tried using next/router but it didn't work out since my NextJS uses the app route

Update:
here is my code:

```js
'use client'
import {
  useRouter
} from 'next/navigation'
import {
  useEffect,
  useState
} from 'react'
import Header from '../Header';

function HeaderLayout({
  children
}) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggelMenu = () => {
    setIsOpen(prev => !prev);
  }
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', () => {
      setIsOpen(false);
    });
  }, [router]);

  return ( <
    >
    <
    Header isOpen = {
      isOpen
    }
    toggelMenu = {
      toggelMenu
    }
    />  {
      children
    } <
    /> 
  )
}
export default HeaderLayout
```

--- Here is the error message:
TypeError: (0 , next_navigation__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.useRouter) is not a function

Comment: @DanielW. I have done that

Comment: next/navigation useRouter [no longer has events](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router#examples).  [usePathname](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-pathname) is the new way to get the `pathname` in Next 13 app dir. There are some caveats when using `usePathname`, I recommend reading the linked Next.js docs page. Try deleteing `.next & node_modules` folders, reinstalling all packages (`npm i`), and restarting your server to fix your issue.